# JSplitPane prevent PropertyChangeEvent when divider moved inside ComponentListener

Tags: java, swing, events

I have a sub-class of a `JSplitPane` which is intended to allow a fixed location of a divider from either the right or bottom edges instead of the left or top.

To that end I am using a `ComponentChangeListener` to catch when the component is resized and recalculate the divider location relative to the width or height.

That all works flawlessly.  But now I am adding a `PropertyChangeListener` to capture the adjusting of a split location by the user and storing that left/top relative value as an offset from the right/bottom border for later use in the resizing.

But I have a kind of cascade problem here:

- You resize the component
- A `ComponentChangeEvent` is triggered
- The divider is moved to the right location
- That causes a `PropertyChangeEvent` to trigger
- Which then recalculates the location of the moved divider using incorrect data

So the divider ends up bouncing all over the place.

I have tried manually putting in an "inhibit" flag (just a simple `boolean`) which *sometimes* works to block the event, but often doesn't, so that's not the way around it.

Any clues?

My `propertyChange` method looks like:

```
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
    if (inhibit) return;
    if (e.getPropertyName().equals("dividerLocation")) {
        int pos = (Integer)e.getNewValue();

        if (right == -1) {
            left = pos;
        } else {
            Dimension d = getSize();
            if (orient == JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT) {
                right = d.height - pos;
            } else {
                right = d.width - pos;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And the `componentResized` is:

```
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    if (!inhibit) {
        updateDividerLocation();
    }
}

void updateDividerLocation() {
    inhibit = true;
    if (right == -1) { // Left / top is fixed
        setDividerLocation(left);
    } else {
        Dimension d = getSize();
        if (orient == JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT) {
            setDividerLocation(d.height - right);
        } else {
            setDividerLocation(d.width - right);
        }
    }
    inhibit = false;
}
```

As you can see I have the `inhibit` flag in there, which as I say doesn't work right.

So what would be the *proper* way of preventing the `setDividerLocation` function from triggering a `PropertyChangeEvent`? Would I have to go as far as removing the `PropertyChangeListener` entirely while resizing the component and adding it again afterwards? Would that even help?

Note: it is most noticeable at times when there may be a bit of lag in the display updates. Here's a SSCCE (though it's not that "Small" I'm afraid) that can demonstrate the problem.  The result of the problem isn't always evident in this SSCCE since there's not much in the window (I find a sharp drag of the right edge towards the left is a good way of messing it up  and a slower, more graphically intensive, LaF helps), but it's very evident in the full program. However the effect can be seen in the fact that resizing the window causes a "CE" output (ComponentEvent) and immediately a "PCE" output (PropertyChangeEvent).  It's that PCE following a CE that I need to suppress.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;

public class TestClass {

    class AbsoluteSplitPane extends JSplitPane implements ComponentListener, PropertyChangeListener {

        int left = -1; // and top
        int right = -1; // and bottom
        int orient;

        public AbsoluteSplitPane(int orientation, Component a, Component b) {
            super(orientation, a, b);
            orient = orientation;
            addComponentListener(this);
            addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        }

        void updateDividerLocation() {
            if (right == -1) { // Left / top is fixed
                setDividerLocation(left);
            } else {
                Dimension d = getSize();
                if (orient == JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT) {
                    setDividerLocation(d.height - right);
                } else {
                    setDividerLocation(d.width - right);
                }
            }
        }

        public void setLeftSize(int s) {
            left = s;
            right = -1;
            updateDividerLocation();
        }

        public void setRightSize(int s) {
            left = -1;
            right = s;
            updateDividerLocation();
        }

        public void setTopSize(int s) {
            left = s;
            right = -1;
            updateDividerLocation();
        }

        public void setBottomSize(int s) {
            left = -1;
            right = s;
            updateDividerLocation();
        }

        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
        }

        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        }

        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        }

        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            updateDividerLocation();
            System.err.println(String.format(" CE: Left: %d Right: %d", left, right));
        }

        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
            if (e.getPropertyName().equals("dividerLocation")) {
                int pos = (Integer)e.getNewValue();

                if (right == -1) {
                    left = pos;
                } else {
                    Dimension d = getSize();
                    if (orient == JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT) {
                        right = d.height - pos;
                    } else {
                        right = d.width - pos;
                    }
                }

                System.err.println(String.format("PCE: Left: %d Right: %d", left, right));
            }
        }
    }

    public TestClass() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Window");

        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        JPanel mid = new JPanel();
        JPanel right = new JPanel();

        AbsoluteSplitPane split1 = new AbsoluteSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, mid, right);
        AbsoluteSplitPane split2 = new AbsoluteSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, left, split1);
        split1.setRightSize(200);
        split2.setLeftSize(200);

        frame.add(split2);

        frame.setSize(400, 400);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestClass();
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** I have managed to hack around the problem by attaching a MouseListener to the divider through the UI  (`((BasicSplitPaneUI)getUI()).getDivider.addMouseListener(...)`) and save the location data on a `mouseReleased()` event. It works, but it'd still be good to know if there is a way of suppressing PropertyChangeEvents...

Comment: Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I'd like to, but that's hard...   I'm working on it at the moment.

Comment: I think I just found a typo in my code.  I may have just solved it and the problem wasn't what I thought (or rather the problem exists but doesn't "cause" a problem...)

Comment: Actually there is still a problem. The double events cause the divider to drift. So I still need some way of blocking them...

Comment: @camickr I've managed to craft one, but the effect is somewhat dependent on timing, and an SSCCE is a lot lighter and doesn't take as long doing display updates. I have debug outputs in it though to indicate the problem regardless.

Answer (score 0):

> but it'd still be good to know if there is a way of suppressing PropertyChangeEvents...

```
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    removePropertyChangeListener( this );
    updateDividerLocation();
    addPropertyChangeListener( this );
    System.err.println(String.format(" CE: Left: %d Right: %d", left, right));
}
```

Edit:

Maybe you can look at the event on the EDT that is causing the PropertyChangeEvent to be generated?

```
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
    {

        if (e.getPropertyName().equals("dividerLocation"))
        {
            AWTEvent event = EventQueue.getCurrentEvent();

            if (event != null
            && (event.getID() != MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED))
                return;

            int pos = (Integer)e.getNewValue();

            if (right == -1) {
                left = pos;
            } else {
                Dimension d = getSize();
                if (orient == JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT) {
                    right = d.height - pos;
                } else {
                    right = d.width - pos;
                }
            }

            System.err.println(String.format("PCE: Left: %d Right: %d", left, right));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Already tried that already. The event is still on the queue and if not handled immediately is still on the queue when you add the listener again. So it sometimes still triggers.

Comment: @Majenko, Can't figure out how to "suppress" the PCE. I looked at the source code of the `setDividerLocation(...)` method to prevent the event from being generated but that method uses private variables so I couldn't override the method. Next approach is to "ignore" the PCE unless it was generated as a result of the mouseReleased event. See edit.

Comment: I too was looking at the swing source. I almost had something by overriding getDividerLocation and setDividerLocation in my subclass, but it didn't quite work out...

Comment: @Majenko, did the "edit" help or is it completely off track?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but TBH if I'm going to be looking at the MouseEvent inside the PropertyChangeEvent handler I may as well just use the MouseEvent handler as I am now.

Comment: *I may as well just use the MouseEvent handler as I am now.* - makes sense, you won't even need the PropertyChangeListener.

Comment: At this point I'm more interested in how stopping the events even being fired in the first place could be achieved. I'm going to keep it using the mouse event (though in theory there could be a UI that uses the keyboard to move the divider which would break it) for this specific instance, but I'd still love to know how it could be done...

Comment: *I'm more interested in how stopping the events even being fired* - agreed. Swing should be single threaded so removing the PropertyChangeListener before setting the divider location should work. Since it doesn't that must mean somewhere in the split pane UI a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...) is used which means some code is not executed sequentially as expected. I also tried wrapping some code in a SwingUtillities.invokeLater() but it didn't seem to help. Maybe I tried wrapping the wrong code? I don't have any further suggestions.

Comment: *there could be a UI that uses the keyboard to move the divider* - there is. You use F8 to start resizing and then the arrow keys to move the divider. See [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for the default bindings on the split pane. You might be able to use my suggestion to check for a mouseReleased or I presume a keyPressed event in order to handle the PCE.